# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1 n \log(1+ {(\frac xn)}^\alpha) dx$ for some $0< \alpha \leq 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, analysis

Evaluate $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1 n \log(1+ {(\frac xn)}^\alpha) dx$$ for some $0< \alpha \leq 1$.

Initially, I was thinking to prove the uniform convergence of $n \log(1+ {(\frac xn)}^\alpha)$ so that I can interchange integration and limit but later I observed that for $0< \alpha < 1$ $n \log(1+ {(\frac xn)}^\alpha) \to \infty$ if $2\alpha>1$ and $n \log(1+ {(\frac xn)}) \to x$ just by expanding the series so it will be complicated in that sense. Is there any way out to solve it easily?

Comment: it would help noticing that $y-y^2/2\le\ln(1+y)\le y$ for $|y|<1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show that
$$
h\ge\log(1+h)\ge \frac{h}{1+h} \tag{1}
$$
for $h\ge 0$, by integrating 
$$
1\ge\frac{1}{1+t}\ge \frac{1}{(1+t)^2}
$$
in $[0,h]$.

**Case 1.** $a=1$.

Then, (1) implies that
$$
x=n\cdot\frac{x}{n}\ge n\log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)\ge n\cdot \frac{\frac{x}{n}}{1+\frac{x}{n}}=\frac{x}{1+\frac{x}{n}}=x-\frac{x^2}{n+x}\ge x-\frac{1}{n}
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{1}{2}=\int_0^1x\,dx\ge\int_0^1 n\log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)\,dx\ge \int_0^1x\,dx-\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\to \frac{1}{2}.
$$

**Case 2.** $0<a<1$.

Hence
$$
n\log\left(1+\frac{x^a}{n^a}\right)\ge n\cdot\frac{\frac{x^a}{n^a}}{1+\frac{x^a}{n^a}}=\frac{nx^a}{n^a+x^a}\ge \frac{nx^a}{n^a}=n^{1-a}x^a,
$$
and thus
$$
\int_0^1 n\log\left(1+\frac{x^a}{n^a}\right)\,dx\ge n^{1-a}\int_0^1 x^a\,dx=\frac{n^{1-a}}{a+1}\to \infty,
$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: For $\alpha =1$ the limit is $\frac  1 2$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy See my modified answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: denote $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}$, $t=\epsilon x$, then
$$
\int_0^1n\log(1+(x/n)^\alpha)\,dx=\frac{\int_0^\epsilon\log(1+t^\alpha)\,dt}{\epsilon^2}.
$$
Now apply [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) ($\epsilon\to 0$).

Answer (score 1):

The limit is $\frac 1 2$ for $\alpha =1$ and $\infty$ for $\alpha <1$. Both of these follows from the fact that $\frac {\log(1+t)} t \to 1$ as $ t \to 0$. [Note that $(\frac x n)^{\alpha} \to 0$ uniformly for $x \in [0,1]$].

Comment: Let me know if you want more details.